# Armature transform matrix

Tags: bones, fcurves

I have a question about how to place bones in a right position.

Let's say I have 3 bones root, mid, and last. And root is a parent of mid, mid is a parent of last, and last is the very end.
As I know that the bones in armature have their own bone.matrix_local. However I am not sure how to use them. Is bone.matrix_local in a space of its parent's?
How can I place bones in the right position that they need to be with f-curve values(position/rotation_quaternion) when animation is running?